# Array to string conversion laravel 5.5 when seeding data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Array to string conversion

**(SQL)**

```
 `insert into `group_members` (`id`, `group_id`, `alias`) values (1, 20, Lilian Marvin PhD)`
```

```
$users =  User::where('role_id','=',3)->select('id','display_name')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $groups =  Group::select('id')->get()->toArray();   
            // echo $user->display_name ." " .$user->id ."<br/>"; 

            DB::table('group_members')->insert([
                'id' => $user->id,
                'group_id' => array_random($groups),
                'alias' => $user->display_name
            ]);
        }
```

in the **array_random**, **I believe there's an error**

Comment: I think the function you want to use is array_rand()

Comment: I would like to know what kind of data group_id stores?

Comment: got an answer nvm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save array in `group_id` column. You need to save only `id` not array

try  this

```
DB::table('group_members')->insert([
        'id' => $user->id,
        'group_id' => array_random($groups)['id'],
        'alias' => $user->display_name
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any one of the group then you can try

```
array_random($groups, 1),
```

if you want to store multiple, then you may like to convert it to json

```
 json_encode(array_random($groups, 1)),
```

Answer (score 0):

used laravel helper method [`Arr::random`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-array-random)

> The `Arr::random` method returns a random value from an array

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$random = Arr::random($array);
```

> // 2 - (retrieved randomly)